# Disable Auto Log Out?

Tags: login

Is there a way, as an Admin, to disable Auto-logout? Not for the whole org, just for myself?

I want to leave my work tabs open without coming in the next day to a lost pallet.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the session expiry setting to a maximum of 24 hours *per profile*. This means that you'd still be logged out over a weekend, but at least for each weekday, you could stay logged in the entire week. To adjust the time, go to setup, and alter the Session Timeout value to 24 hours. If you wanted to enable this just for you, and not other admins, you'd need to create a custom profile, have another admin move you to the custom profile, and adjust the session settings from there.

Comment: That was a miss! Didn't realize this when writing the answer and that this can be actually be a route to achieve that.

Comment: @JayantDas Yeah, it's a pretty new feature, I wouldn't expect most people to remember it (I myself had to double-check it before I answered).

Comment: And I just referenced your answer to make mine's a bit more comprehensive :)

Comment: @sfdcfox So Setup>Security Controls>Session Settings>Session Timeout: 

"Set the session security and session expiration timeout for your organization."
Session Timeout = X#

If I change this, is it just for me or is it for all the users on in my "Organization"?

Comment: @Man That's the "whole organization" setting. Look for the similar setting found under Setup > Manage Users > Profiles.

Comment: @sfdcfox Ahh got it & awesome, Tyvm! Now I can login where I left off w/o crying. Thanks Fox

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED (to make it comprehensive and reference the approach as recommended by sfdcfox)**

As far as I can say, you **cannot** for an individual. While you can modify the Session Security Settings, but that is applicable across the organization or on a profile.

The Session timeout value is controlled by the attribute `Timeout Value` under Session Security Settings in setup and that it can be set based on the available values (min 15 mins, max 24 hours). You can find more on this topic on the following links:

- [Session Security](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_overview_sessions.htm&type=5)
- [Modify Session Security Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_sessions.htm&type=0)
- [View and Edit Session Settings in Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_session.htm&type=5)

As for the profile approach, refer to the other [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/232127/54851).